# Calculate the rule if given the totalistic rule

Tags: cellular-automata

I was wondering how is it possible to get the rule number if you are given the totalistic rule? I want to have the ruleplot but im given the totalistic rule.
I have done this but since my totalistic rule is 2007 it doesnt work

```
BaseForm[2007,3]\[IndentingNewLine]
RulePlot[CellularAutomaton[2007]]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include enough copy-paste-able Mathematica code that allows forum participants to replicate your problem in their notebooks. It is called a "minimal working example" and ensures a focused interaction.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Try `RulePlot[CellularAutomaton[{2007, {3, 1}}]]`